# sum of two numbers in java using two classes

Tags: java

I want to make sum of two numbers. But I have problems to do that. I don't understand why my sum is always zero.

class A

```
 public class A {
 int a=3 ,b=4;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 B obj= new B();
 obj.prod();
}
}
```

CLASS B

```
 public class B {

int a, b;
public void prod()
{
    System.out.print(a+b);
}

}
```

Comment: you never initialize `a` and `b` in class `B` so they are by default set to `0`; and `0 + 0 = 0`

Comment: `a` and `b` in class `A` have nothing to do with `a` and `b` in class `B`. Primitive fields have a default value when not intialized, which is `0` for `int`s

Comment: So how to print 7 using two classes

Comment: pass the values from class A as parameters to the prod method

Comment: Minor nitpick: your method name should fit what it does. Adding two numbers produces a sum, not a product. Instead of `prod()` your method should be named `printSum()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninitialized primitive fields have a default value. In the case of `int` this value is `0`.

To pass the values from class `A` to `B` you should implement a *constructor* which takes two arguments.

```
public class B {
    int a, b;

    public B(int a, int b) 
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void prod()
    {
        System.out.print(a+b);
    }

}
```

Then in your class `A`, call the constructor of `B` like this:

```
 public class A {
     int a=3 ,b=4;
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         B obj= new B(a, b);
         obj.prod();
     }
}
```

Another way is to give your method `prod()` the parameters:

```
public void prod(int a, int b)
{
    System.out.print(a+b);
}
```

And then call it:

```
public class A {
     int a=3 ,b=4;
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         B obj= new B();
         obj.prod(a, b);
     }
}
```

Comment: your answer helped.thanks

Comment: nice description. really helped

Answer (score 1):

```
   public class A {
   int a=3 ,b=4;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   B obj= new B();
  obj.prod(a,b);
 } 
}

 public class B {
 public void prod(int a, int b)
{
 System.out.print(a+b);
} 

}
```

Comment: Thanks ur answer helped

Comment: ya. will do it after 7 mins

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code will help you:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create object B, passing aa=3, bb=4 to B's constructor
        B objectB = new B(3, 4);

        // this will return result as "12"
        int result = objectB.prod();
    }

}

public class B {
    // declare member variables
    private final int a;
    private final int b;

    // B's constructor
    public B (int aa, int bb) {
        // set values passed in to member variables
        this.a = aa;
        this.b = bb;
    }

    public int prod() {
        int result = this.a + this.b;

        // print result
        System.out.print(result + "");

        // return result to caller
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the values in class A. These are not available in class B. Either pass in constructor of class B or pass to the method prod().
You need to modify your class as below :

```
public class A {
 int a = 3, b = 4;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  B obj = new B(a, b);
  obj.prod();
 }
}

public class B {

 int a, b;

 b(int a, int b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
 }
 public void prod() {
  System.out.print(a + b);
 }

}
//OR
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
public class A {
 int a = 3, b = 4;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  B obj = new B();
  obj.prod(a, b);
 }
}
//CLASS B

public class B {

 int a, b;
 public void prod(int a, int b) {
  System.out.print(a + b);
 }

}
```